# "The pseudoclassical and prototypal paradigms for creating new objects".How to decide which one to use

Tags: javascript

Since **Classical inheritence** is well understood both in javascript and the programmer community and  almost all object-oriented code written in javaScript uses this paradigm.
**Also prototypal inheritance is very memory efficient.** 
I am designing an API for javascript but could not decide which one to use for my API

Comment: *"...almost all object-oriented code written in javaScript uses this paradigm"* Stats please.

Comment: _"Does prototypal feature of javascript is on the verge of getting extinct?"_ No. It's at the heart of the language.

Comment: No, prototype inheritance is nowhere near on the verge of extinction. The opposite is probably true, as more and more developers are understanding it and using it properly.

Comment: **There is no classical inheritance in JavaScript**. Anything resembling that (including ES6's `class` construct) is just syntactic sugar over prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @JosephSilber He said `pseudoclassical` in the title.

Comment: @Paulpro - Correct. All I'm saying is that since the [psuedo]classical inheritance is built on top of prototypical inheritance, there's no way it is going anywhere.

Comment: @JosephSilber Right, sorry. I misunderstood your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to decide which one to use

It's simple, there's not that much difference between the purely prototypical and the pseudoclassical approach. Just one question:

**Do you need constructors/initialisers?**